# nmap in bash script returns error

Tags: scripts, nmap

I want to find out all my available routers with `nmap`.

Typing this in command line returns the expected output.

```
nmap --script=broadcast-dchp-discover -e eno1
```

---

But when I try to run this command in a short bash script `nmap` returns an error:

```
NSE: failed to initialize the script engine:
/usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:801: 'broadcast-dchp-discover' did not match a category, filename, or directory
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        /usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:801: in function 'get_chosen_scripts'
        /usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:1251: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `broadcast-dchp-discover` a file or directory?

Comment: broadcast-dchp-discover is a file that came with the installation of nmap

Comment: Could it be a problem of running the script from the wrong working directory? Maybe try and add a `cd` to the script or use the full absolute path instead of relative.

Comment: Using the absolute path `/usr/share/nmap/scripts/broadcast-dchp-discover.nse` didn't work.

Comment: We can't help you debug a script you don't show us. Please [edit] your question and include the script you are running and the command you use to execute your script.

Comment: I found what's wrong in the script.
I made a typo at dhcp `broadcast-dchp-discover` should be `broadcast-dhcp-discover`

Comment: Whoops, sorry.  Didn't see your comment below the fold. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you typed "dhcp" to me. Change this:

```
broadcast-dchp-discover
```

To use dhcp**d**:

```
broadcast-dchpd-discover
```